# leaflet: Detect when marker is out of view

Tags: javascript, leaflet, visible

I have a table with geo location results in which the user can click to set that location in the map. The map is already loaded, and the user might have paned/scolled, and all those locations might be out of sight.

So when the user clicks the button for a location in the table, I need to check if that marker is already visible in the map. And only if invisible, call to `setView` and zoom into that location; otherwise, I just change the color of the marker (no pan, no zoom).

Has leaflet any API to check if a layer/marker is currenlty been rendered in the map?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Probably `map.getBounds().contains(myMarker.getLatLng())`

References:

- [`map.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds) Returns the LatLngBounds of the current map view.
- [`myLatLngBounds.contains()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains) Returns `true` if the rectangle contains the given point.
- [`marker.getLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-getlatlng) Returns the current geographical position of the marker.